# "I" instead of "We"

Tags: grammatical-number

In Toronto, when you ask for something in a store and they don't have it, the person you ask  will usually respond "I don't have it". Is this something related to the English language itself that I don't understand, or it is just the local culture? I would expect "We don't have it" or "The store doesn't have" or any other form, but not "I don't have it". Or maybe it is normal to native speakers?

Not only in Toronto, in Niagara Falls, in a restaurant or cafe, you'll hear "I don't have it" very often. And addressing the comments, not from the owner or the only worker.

Comment: I am not native but it sounds perfectly ok to me. Especially if it is the owner or the manager of the store you are talking to

Comment: If there's only one clerk in the store and he said to me *"We don't have it"*, then I'll be sorely tempted to reply, *"What 'we'? Do you have a mouse in your pocket?"*

Comment: @F.E. that's interesting. I'm not a native speaker and "we" sounds more usual to. I wouldn't expect to hear "I" unless the person owning the business is the one answering your questions.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's a matter of interpretation *by the store clerk* of the sense of the customer's question, "Do you have X?" If the clerk understands the question as being essentially person-to-person, the natural answer is "Yes, I do," or "No, I don't." If the the clerk understands it as being essentially person-to-establishment, the answer just as reasonably comes out "Yes, we do" or "No, we don't." From the OP's examples, I suspect that clerks in Toronto have a stronger tendency than do clerks elsewhere to interpret the question as assuming and inviting a person-to-person relationship.

That there is a sliding scale of personal relationship and personal acknowledgment in customer-clerk interactions is clear from the fact that, even in a city that tends to have highly impersonal customer-clerk interactions, a customer who asks "Which of these two products is better?" is likely to be surprised if the clerk responds "We prefer that one."

In the U.S. South (at least when I was growing up there), the customer could frame the question as personal or impersonal by asking either "Do you have X?" or "Do y'all have X?"

Answer (score 0):

Nah, that's normal usage. It depends entirely where the person you asked positions him/herself in that situation with their company.

Some like to remain neutral and go with The store, some take a more direct approach and go with I, others again like to be part of the company and go with we.

On top of that it also depends how you ask them. There's no correct or wrong usage in this case.